# An interesting probability question - sampling populations that exchange information

Tags: probability, sampling

A biologist colleague of mine posed the following probability (with replacement) question to me. Based on his language (English is his second language), it's not clear to me how to proceed. When pressed for a clearer explanation, he is unable to clarify. Thus, I am asking here on CV.

Now for the question...

There are two populations, $A$ and $B$.

In population $A$, we have sampled 577 individuals. These individuals are numbered, with some individuals having identical numbers. Altogether, 99 unique numbers are observed. We think there could be 207 total unique numbers comprising both observed and unobserved unique numbers (thus, 207 - 99 = 108 unobserved unique numbers).

In population $B$, we have sampled 428 individuals. These individuals are numbered, with some individuals having identical numbers. Altogether, 15 unique numbers are observed. We think there could be 47 total unique numbers comprising both observed and unobserved unique numbers (thus, 47 - 15 = 32 unobserved unique numbers).

Some individuals are able to migrate freely from population $B$ to population $A$. Further, we observe some unique numbers in population $A$ that are found in population $B$ (but that haven't been sampled in population $B$).

(1) **What is the probability that 5 random unique numbers ARE NOT sampled in population $B$, given that 577 individuals have been sampled?**

(2) **What is the probability that 5 random unique numbers ARE sampled in population $A$ given that 428 individuals have been sampled?**

We assume the unique numbers DO NOT all have the same probability of being selected (thanks @whuber).

Here, "individuals" are animal species that have been collected, while the unique random numbers represent their "genetic types" (DNA sequences). The total number of unique values was calculated using an R package called iNEXT (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iNEXT/index.html). The unique types follow a discrete probability distribution. For instance, supposing there are only 3 types, "Type I" might have a frequency of 50%, "Type 2" 25% and "Type 3" 25%. With 99 and 15 observed types, their corresponding distributions would be too verbose to detail here. However, we can assume that unobserved types occur at very low frequency within the populations; thus, their contribution to the overall probability distribution is negligible.

More concretely, the question has been posed in the context of invasive species. Population $A$ is North America and Population $B$ is Europe. Individual species have migrated from Europe to North America and are now invasive.

In the end, my colleague will multiply these two obtained probabilities together. The result would (to him) correspond to the probability that the 5 random unique numbers did NOT originate from population $A$. However, to me, the events don't seem independent. Thus, summing the results is more correct.

If the scenario and/or questions are not clear, I'll try to clarify, but even I am a bit lost given his explanation.

This seems like a classic urn problem in which urns are connected to one another.

I think a solution could be simulated, but I believe my colleague wants a closed-form expression.

Comment: Your assumption about "same probability of being selected" appears to be at odds with your description. In a population of 577 with 207 unique numbers, there's an average of  2.8 individuals per number. If you're selecting numbers uniformly, then you can't be selecting individuals uniformly. How does the selection work, then? Could you please tell us what these "individuals" and "numbers" actually are; how individuals acquire numbers; how individuals move among populations; and how you know (or assume) what the total number of distinct numbers is?

Comment: Yes. I will try to clarify.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the correction. I've added some further information. Hopefully it is clear enough to be able to formulate a way forward.